# Simple unix commands

Tags: linux, unix

I just recently started to work on unix. I am trying wrap my head around a few things. 
Hope you guys can help me.

1) How would I print out all the lines of a file that contain a certain word a certain times?
I know I need to use GREP command? But i can be wrong. It confuses me how two or more commands can be used together in a single command.

grep 'word' filename I know this would give me the words that are in that file but how do I make it so that I get the lines that contain that word twice for instance?

2) How would I print the lines that contain only numbers or characters?

3) How would I print the lines that start with numbers? For instance Im reading a file that has questions written in it. Questions start with numbers like "3)wha...." .So I would like to print those onto the screen.

4) How would I print lines that end with numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try learn regular expression first.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are really looking for a primer in regex. This isn't really the site for that. Google "regex primer".

Comment: Start with `man man`. Then `man intro`. Then `man grep`.

Comment: http://linuxcommand.org/ : you'll find there quite a good primer on the Shell, and its use, on common commands, and on shell scripting as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines that start with numbers:

```
grep '^\d' fileName.txt
```

Lines that end with number:

```
grep '\d$' fileName.txt
```

Lines containing only numbers:

```
grep '^\d+$' fileName.txt
```

Lines containing `word` three times:

```
egrep '(word.*){3}' fileName.txt
```

(Not sure the last one will work... Bit I think so)

And so on... Lots to learn, not enough space to explain it all here.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm trying to learn how to put them together so I can do it myself. thanks for the start up though!